# Array of struct pointers, invalid initializer error, in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, initialization

This code:

```
extern void *malloc(unsigned int);
struct Box {
    int x, y ,w, h;
};

struct Wall {
    char color[15];
    struct Box *boxes[20];
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    struct Wall *mywall = malloc(sizeof(struct Wall));
    struct Box *myboxes[] = mywall->boxes;
    return 0;
}
```

gives me `invalid initializer` error at line 14. What I am trying to do, is to get a copy of array of struct pointers, which are in a different struct.

Comment: You cannot copy or assign arrays in C. (However, you can wrap them up into a struct, which *can* be assigned.)

Comment: Why not `#include <stdlib.h>` instead of `extern void *malloc(unsigned int);
`?

Comment: @glglgl no particular reason. I wrote this piece of code just to demonstrate my point. I forgot where was malloc, and was too lazy to look for it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Returning an array of char pointers](/q/2118218/90527)", "[Assign to 2D array a 2D array in a struct](/q/6770507/90527)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ouch; there are a number of problems here.

```
extern void *malloc(unsigned int);
```

Don't do that; use `#include <stdlib.h>` because that will be correct and what you wrote is typically incorrect (the argument to `malloc()` is a `size_t`, which is not necessarily an `unsigned int`; it might be `unsigned long`, or some other type).

```
struct Box {
    int x, y ,w, h;
};
```

Apart from erratic space, `struct Box` is OK.

```
struct Wall {
    char color[15];
    struct Box *boxes[20];
};
```

And `struct Wall` is OK too.

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
```

You aren't using `argc` or `argv`, so you'd be better using the alternative declaration of:

```
int main(void)
```

Original code again:

```
{
    struct Wall *mywall = malloc(sizeof(struct Wall));
```

This allocates but does not initialize a single `struct Wall`.  Of itself, it is OK, though you should check that the allocation succeeded before you use it.  You also need to worry about allocating the `struct Box` items that the elements of the array will point to.

```
    struct Box *myboxes[] = mywall->boxes;
```

You've got a minor catastrophe on hand here.  You can't copy arrays like that.  You haven't checked that you've got an array.  Ignoring the error checking, you are stuck with one of:

```
    struct Box *myboxes[] = { &mywall->boxes[0], &mywall->boxes[1], ... };
```

or:

```
    struct Box **myboxes = &mywall->boxes;
```

I'm not convinced that you'd want the second version, for all it's shorter.

```
    return 0;
```

I like to see `return 0;` at the end of `main()`, even though C99 allows you to omit it.

```
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
struct Box **myboxes = mywall->boxes;
```

?

Then you can do stuff like:

```
 for ( int i = 0 ; i < 15 ; i++ )
    mywall->boxes[i] = malloc(sizeof(Box));
 Box* x = myboxes[1];
```

As the code is now, `mywall->boxes` isn't initialized.

NOTE: just re-read the question - this won't return a copy of the array, but point to the same location. There's no short solution for a copy without using `memcpy` or just copying the structs.